# Android Development: File Browser For Reading/Saving Files

Tags: android, file, browser

Does anyone know any good tutorials for this please?
Or could anyone run me through some basic code for making this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really need to write your own? Because you could just use `intent`s and use someone else's file browser.

Comment: I was thinking about doing that using ES File Explorer, but I was just worried that it would annoy customers having to download another application if they don't have it.

Comment: Is the File Explorer a core feature of your app? Or just a side-feature? In any case, I would try it the easy way first, then you could always write your own custom file browser later on (assuming your users are really dissatisfied, which personally I don't think they will be. The way Android does intents, and possibly opens up the right Market application page if needed, it actually works surprisingly well for users).

Comment: The file explorer will just be used to read and save to files, the app is basically a text editor, so it is major, but yeah I'm just going to use intents for now. Thanks for the help :)